# PHP IDE for mac which shows a list of all declared functions?

Tags: php, macos, list, function, ide

I'd been searching for a php IDE which will list and auto complete declared functions.
No luck with Aptana and Komodo Edit.

Codelobster for windows is something that I want and light weight too. But there's no mac version.

Anyone seen any around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use NetBeans.

http://netbeans.org/

> Most developers recognize the NetBeans IDE as the original free Java IDE. It is that, and much more! The NetBeans IDE provides support for several languages (PHP, JavaFX, C/C++, JavaScript, etc.) and frameworks.

http://netbeans.org/about/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I was using Panic Coda for several years now and it's a best PHP/Web development tool for mac out there: http://panic.com/coda/

Comment: Coda isn't an IDE. Coda is basically an FTP/SSH client that also has a text editor that highlights code for you. Don't get me wrong, it's fine for simple tasks, but for writing a PHP script it isn't the best route to take.

Comment: I think you just do not know coda's capabilities enough, it's far from being just text editor which highlights code. To my knowledge IDE stands for Integrated Development Environment and I do not know how coda doesn't feet in this definition.